# How to use the SELECT, WHERE and AND command in selecting data from a table which also avoids repetiton

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `Class`, `Student`, and a join table `StudentInTheClass`.

Class:

```
+------+
| cid  |
+------+
| C001 |
| C002 |
| C003 |
+------+
```

Student:

```
+------+
| sid  |
+------+
| S001 |
| S005 |
| S003 |
| S004 |
| S007 |
| S002 |
| S006 |
+------+
```

StudentInTheClass:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+
| studentClassId | sId   | cId   |
+----------------+-------+-------+
| SC1            | S001  | C001  |
| SC2            | S001  | C002  |
| SC3            | S002  | C001  |
| SC4            | S002  | C002  |
| SC5            | S002  | C003  |
| SC6            | S003  | C003  |
+----------------+-------+-------+
```

How can I select class id's that do not belong to a specific student. For example, for student `S001` the result should be `C003`.

Comment: thank you very much. i'm new to this SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dot product of Student and Class then exclude entries from your StudentInClass join table.

Dot product of all students and classes:

```
mysql> SELECT *
         FROM Student
         INNER JOIN Class;
+------+------+
| sid  | cid  |
+------+------+
| S001 | C001 |
| S001 | C002 |
| S001 | C003 |
| S002 | C001 |
| S002 | C002 |
| S002 | C003 |
| S003 | C001 |
| S003 | C002 |
| S003 | C003 |
| S004 | C001 |
| S004 | C002 |
| S004 | C003 |
| S005 | C001 |
| S005 | C002 |
| S005 | C003 |
| S006 | C001 |
| S006 | C002 |
| S006 | C003 |
| S007 | C001 |
| S007 | C002 |
| S007 | C003 |
+------+------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Outer joined to the join table:

```
mysql> SELECT *
         FROM Student
         INNER JOIN Class
         LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentInTheClass ON (
           StudentInTheClass.sId = Student.sid
             AND StudentInTheClass.cId = Class.cid
         );
+------+------+----------------+------+------+
| sid  | cid  | studentClassId | sid  | cid  |
+------+------+----------------+------+------+
| S001 | C001 | SC1            | S001 | C001 |
| S001 | C002 | SC2            | S001 | C002 |
| S002 | C001 | SC3            | S002 | C001 |
| S002 | C002 | SC4            | S002 | C002 |
| S002 | C003 | SC5            | S002 | C003 |
| S003 | C003 | SC6            | S003 | C003 |
| S001 | C003 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S003 | C001 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S003 | C002 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S004 | C001 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S004 | C002 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S004 | C003 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S005 | C001 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S005 | C002 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S005 | C003 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S006 | C001 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S006 | C002 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S006 | C003 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S007 | C001 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S007 | C002 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
| S007 | C003 | NULL           | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+----------------+------+------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now we can filter down to combinations which don't exist in the join:

```
mysql> SELECT Student.sid, Class.cid
         FROM Student
         INNER JOIN Class
         LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentInTheClass ON (
           StudentInTheClass.sId = Student.sid
             AND StudentInTheClass.cId = Class.cid
         )
         WHERE StudentInTheClass.studentClassId IS NULL;
+------+------+
| sid  | cid  |
+------+------+
| S001 | C003 |
| S003 | C001 |
| S003 | C002 |
| S004 | C001 |
| S004 | C002 |
| S004 | C003 |
| S005 | C001 |
| S005 | C002 |
| S005 | C003 |
| S006 | C001 |
| S006 | C002 |
| S006 | C003 |
| S007 | C001 |
| S007 | C002 |
| S007 | C003 |
+------+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now you can select by student:

```
mysql> SELECT Class.cid
         FROM Student
         INNER JOIN Class
         LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentInTheClass ON (
           StudentInTheClass.sId = Student.sid
             AND StudentInTheClass.cId = Class.cid
         )
         WHERE StudentInTheClass.studentClassId IS NULL
           AND Student.sid = "S001";
+------+
| cid  |
+------+
| C003 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just like algebra, some parts of this query are now redundant and can be cancelled out. `StudentInClass.sId = Student.sid` and `Student.sid = "S001"` means `StudentInClass.sId = "S001"` so we can remove our reference to the `Student` table:

```
mysql> SELECT Class.cid
         FROM Class
         LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentInTheClass ON (
           StudentInTheClass.sId = "S001"
             AND StudentInTheClass.cId = Class.cid
         )
         WHERE StudentInTheClass.studentClassId IS NULL;
+------+
| cid  |
+------+
| C003 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that we can't cancel out the reference to `Class` because we're testing for the absence of rows in the joined `StudentInTheClass` table so there would be nothing to select for a result if we tried.

Comment: thank you very much can you tel me where can i learn sql more.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this to exclude classes where the student and class exist in the StudentInTheClass table:

```
SELECT c.cId FROM Class c 
LEFT JOIN StudentInTheClass sc ON c.cId=sc.cId AND sc.sId='S001'
WHERE sc.studentClassId IS NULL
```

Comment: thank you very much. I cant do more my reputation is so low.

Comment: you should at least be able to accept the answer. No worries if you can't

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: No it's not, the result is the same but this is a simpler way to do it that should execute faster as well.